# Can I use a function as a conditional attribute

Tags: polymer

In the following code, I want to use a function as a condition attribute:

```
<polymer-element name="test-element">
    <template>
        <select id="type_menu" on-change="{{ onSelected }}">
            <option value="0" disabled?="{{ isDisabled }}">Item 0</option>
            <option value="0" disabled?="{{ isDisabled }}">Item 1</option>
            <option value="0" disabled?="{{ isDisabled }}">Item 2</option>
        </select>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('test-element', {
            onSelected: function(event, details, sender) {
                // do something here
            },
            isDisabled: function() {
                return false; // simplified here - it doesn't matter, it always returns true
            }
        }
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So far, I have not been able to make this work. I have tried using disabled?="{{ isDisabled() }}" also. Can it be done at all? If not, what is the best way to do this with some kind of function? Setting a data property on ready might work but it seems a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Solved it. Use a filter.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer with an example, so that others who have this issue have something to build on?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how I solved it:

```
<polymer-element name="test-element">
<template>
    <select id="type_menu" on-change="{{ onSelected }}">
        <option value="0" disabled?="{{ someData[0].val | isDisabled }}">Item 0</option>
        <option value="1" disabled?="{{ someData[1].val | isDisabled }}">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2" disabled?="{{ someData[2].val | isDisabled }}">Item 2</option>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('test-element', {
        ready: function() {
            // in this case, I'm just using read to put in some simple values to filter
            this.someData = [{
                    val = 0
                },{
                    val = 1
                },{
                    val = 2
             }];
        },
        onSelected: function(event, details, sender) {
            // do something here
        },
        isDisabled: function(val) {
            return val < 2;
        }
    }
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

This is a very simple example, but the gist is this:

The conditional attribute binding ( disabled? = {{ }} ) expects a value ( {{ value }} ) or a value and a filter separated by a pipe ( {{ value | filter }} ). If you give it a function as the value, I believe it evaluates the truthiness of the function directly (does not run it) - ie someFunctionName == true as opposed to someFunctionName() == true. In that context, someFunctionName will always be truthy because it's evaluating the existence of the function (not undefined or not null, etc.) as opposed to a value the function might return.

In the fix, I'm using a filter, which IS evaluated as a function return (and is passed the value). If, in the fix shown here, I were only to include the value, the first option would be disabled and the others would be enabled (because 0 is falsey). If I pass it the filter, though, the function can evaluate the value based upon its algorithm.

This really becomes useful when you're using an inner template with a loop to populate some list based upon data and you want to set disabled, selected, (whatever) dynamically.